# How to copy multiple files with a same name from children directory to another directory without losing the parent directory?

Tags: file-copy

I've little inconvenience while copying image files from another Android Project to my current one.

Suppose I've files called `nice_little_icon.png` in each of the directories `drawable-ldpi`, `drawable-mdpi`, `drawable-hdpi`, `drawable-xhdpi` and `drawable-xxhdpi`, which are under `res` directory of Project1.

Now how do I copy these files into project2's `res` directory using single Linux/Unix command?

so my end result will look like

```
Project1/../res/drawable-ldpi/nice_little_icon.png -> Project2/../res/drawable-ldpi/nice_little_icon.png
Project1/../res/drawable-mdpi/nice_little_icon.png -> Project2/../res/drawable-mdpi/nice_little_icon.png
Project1/../res/drawable-hdpi/nice_little_icon.png -> Project2/../res/drawable-mdpi/nice_little_icon.png
Project1/../res/drawable-xhdpi/nice_little_icon.png -> Project2/../res/drawable-xhdpi/nice_little_icon.png
Project1/../res/drawable-xxhdpi/nice_little_icon.png -> Project2/../res/drawable-xxhdpi/nice_little_icon.png
```

Comment: Have a look at the `pax` manual.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`pax`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/pax.html) command (a standardized replacement for `tar` and `cpio`). This command is present on all POSIX-compliant systems, but beware that some Linux distributions omit it from their default installation. `pax` copies each path under the destination directory.

```
pax -rw -pe drawable-*/nice_little_icon.png ../../Project2/res/
```

Instead of relying on wildcards in the shell, you can use the `-s` option to ignore some files.

```
pax -rw -pe -'s!^drawable-[^/]*/nice_little_icon\.png$!&!' -'s!.*/.*!!' drawable-* ../../Project2/res/
```

Comment: Really Cool, man. I tried this too... Awesomeness... Works like a charm

Comment: Sadly I couldn't up vote this... Don't have enough reputation

Answer (score 2):

You can use `rsync`.

```
rsync -avzh -n --include='*/' --include='*nice_little_icon.png' --exclude='*' Project1/../res/ Project2/../res/
```

This will only copy the files called `nice_little_icon.png` from `Project1/../res/*` to `Project2/../res/`, and will create the file's parent directories (`drawable-ldpi`, `drawable-ldpi`, etc.) under `Project2/../res/` if they don't exist.

Explaining the `rsync` command:

- `-avzh` : `-a` basically means 'recursive, and preserve the timestamp, permissions, and a few other things', `-v` means verbose, `-z` means compress files while transferring (not really needed but I like to use it anyways), and `-h` means print in human readable.
- `-n` : means dry-run. So running this command won't do anything. You'll need to remove this to actually make the command take action.
- `--include='*/' --include='*nice_little_icon.png' --exclude='*'` : this is basically the way to tell `rsync` to only copy the files ending in `nice_little_icon.png` and exclude everything else.
- `Project1/../res/` : the source directory. The last `/` is *very* important, it means 'copy whatever is *under* `res/`'. If you removed that `/`, it will copy the actual directory `res` to the destination, which is not what you want.
- `Project2/../res/` : the destination directory.

When you run the above command, it will show you what it's going to do (i.e. what directories and files it will copy):

```
./
drawable-hdpi/
drawable-hdpi/nice_little_icon.png
drawable-mdpi/
drawable-mdpi/nice_little_icon.png
...
```

It should look something like that (i.e. the parent directories, and only the file `nice_little_icon.png`). If it looks okay, **remove the `-n` from the command to actually make it take action and copy the files**.

Comment: Woovvvv... Cool answer.. Thanks for the amazing help... Although once little concern. Wouldn't this use the network to copy the file (I mean over ssh)? So wouldn't it make little expensive operation for a simple file copy?

Comment: Our source directory is `Project1/../res/` and destination directory is `Project2/../res/`. This tells `rsync` that the copy is local, so it won't do it over the network. `rsync` is a copying tool. It was probably initially developed and optimized to do copies over the network (and maybe you've always seen it used for remote copying), but it can be used for local copying just fine, like we're using it here. If our destination was something like this: `10.0.1.2:Project2/../res/`, then yes, that tells `rsync` to copy those files to this server over SSH, but that's not what we're doing here =).

Comment: Ya you're right... I checked the man page of the rsync command. Nicely documented there as you said. Thanks